# Cannot redeclare block scoped variable

Tags: typescript, require

I'm building a node app, and inside each file in .js used to doing this to require in various packages.

```
let co = require("co");
```

But getting

[image]

etc. So using typescript it seems there can only be one such declaration/require across the whole project? 
I'm confused about this as I thought `let` was scoped to the current file.

I just had a project that was working but after a refactor am now getting these errors all over the place.

Can someone explain?

Comment: How about this - let co_module = require("co"); I faced something similar and this solved the error.

Comment: This seems to be a typescript bug. I've made a minimal example here: https://gist.github.com/rjmunro/428ec644b6e53a499ca3a5ba8de2edc7

Comment: 2.5 years later and I'm back at my own question, this is still a problem. this time with node built ins. `const fs = require('fs')` gives similar error so not sure what library to import this from...

Comment: The fact TS still does this is ridiculous

Answer (score 165, accepted):

The best explanation I could get is from [Tamas Piro's post](https://web.archive.org/web/20180609155906/http://fullstack-developer.academy/cannot-redeclare-block-scoped-variable-name/).

TLDR;
TypeScript uses the DOM typings for the global execution environment. In your case there is a 'co' property on the global window object.

To solve this:

1. Rename the variable, or
2. Use TypeScript modules, and add an empty export{}:

   ```
   export {};
   ```

   or
3. Configure your compiler options by not adding DOM typings:

Edit tsconfig.json in the TypeScript project directory.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es6"]
      }
}
```

Comment: this is for client side? my original problem was with server side code and I don't believe the DOM compiler options were being used (old project)

Comment: I confirm that adding `export {}` did solve the problem to me, however adding `"compilerOptions": { "lib": ["es6"] }` does NOT seem to help neither during compilation neither in VSCode.

Comment: This solved my issue, but I wonder what were the reasons they had to take such a decision. I don't have a problem adding `export {}` on a file, but if I'd had some 30 files that would be annoying.

Comment: the 3rd solution resolved a different issue raised when using DOM reserved names (which by the suggested practice omits the DOM typings). it doesn't resolve the issue raised here

Comment: If you use import in stead of require to import the module it we dont need to do anything

Answer (score 98):

Regarding the error itself, `let` is used to declare *local* variables that exist in [block scopes](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/let.html) instead of function scopes. It's also more strict than `var`, so you can't do stuff like this:

```
if (condition) {
    let a = 1;
    ...
    let a = 2;
}
```

Also note that `case` clauses inside `switch` blocks don't create their own block scopes, so you can't redeclare the same local variable across multiple `case`s without using `{}` to create a block each.

---

As for the import, you are probably getting this error because TypeScript doesn't recognize your files as actual modules, and seemingly model-level definitions end up being global definitions for it.

Try importing an external module the standard [ES6](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/1983) way, which contains no explicit assignment, and should make TypeScript recognize your files correctly as modules:

```
import * as co from "./co"
```

This will still result in a compile error if you have something named `co` already, as expected. For example, this is going to be an error:

```
import * as co from "./co"; // Error: import definition conflicts with local definition
let co = 1;
```

---

If you are getting an error *"cannot find module co"*...

TypeScript is running full type-checking against modules, so if you don't have TS definitions for the module you are trying to import (e.g. because it's a JS module without definition files), you can *declare* your module in a `.d.ts` definition file that doesn't contain module-level exports:

```
declare module "co" {
    declare var co: any;
    export = co;
}
```

Comment: this gives "cannot find module co". I also tried `typings install co` which gives `Unable to find "co" in the registry`. any other ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same issue as @dcsan it says it can't find the module even though I clearly have it npm installed.

Comment: It might be caused by the relative path. I'm not familiar with NodeJS module management, but in RequireJS if modules are referenced relatively, the current folder must be explicitly denoted. That is, `./co` instead of `co`, if co.ts is in the same folder (or the compiled output, co.js).

Comment: be attentive, "* as xxx" is important. So, not "import xxx from ..." but "import * as xxx from ..."

Comment: I was not able to use imports in my nodejs app until I added this to my `tsconfig.json`:`"module": "commonjs"`

Comment: > Also note that `case` clauses inside `switch` blocks don't create their own block scopes, so you can't redeclare the same local variable across multiple cases without using `{}` to create a block each.

That solved the issue I was experiencing.

Answer (score 62):

For those coming here in this age, here is a simple solution to this issue. It at least worked for me in the backend. I haven't checked with the frontend code.

Just add:

```
export {};
```

at the top of any files with code without an existing export.

Credit to [EUGENE MURAVITSKY](https://medium.com/@muravitskiy.mail/cannot-redeclare-block-scoped-variable-varname-how-to-fix-b1c3d9cc8206)

Comment: what about files with existing `export`s

Comment: It doesn't matter the content of the file, adding the empty import at the top fixes the issue

Answer (score 31):

I have also dealt with this issue while working with ts on vscode. The way i fix this is easy, but it might not be the same as your problem.

My editor shows this error when i have the typescript file and the javascript file open at the same time in the recent tabs. I just close it and the error goes away.

Hope this helps someone who may also be scratching their head from this simple bug.

Comment: A great answer that solves the problem, thanks! The error takes place only when both .ts and .js files are opened in Vscode simultaneousely, and after closing a .js file the problem is gone.

Comment: This answer isn't relevant for those getting the error from the ts compiler

Answer (score 15):

I was receiving this similar error when compiling my Node.JS Typescript application:

`node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:83:15 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'custom'.`

The fix was to **remove** this:

```
"files": [
  "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts"
]
```

and to replace it with this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "types": ["node"]
}
```

Answer (score 15):

This is solved via "moduleDetection": "force" in your tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleDetection": "force"
  }
}
```

Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleDetection

Original anwser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74968079/10538886

Comment: best and clean answer, if this option does not have some other implication!

Answer (score 14):

Use `IIFE(Immediately Invoked Function Expression)`, [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

```
(function () {
    all your code is here...

 })();
```

Comment: Simple. Works perfectly. Thank you!
(In my case, I was declaring `const expect = chai.expect;` in order to use Cucumber tests in Angular 5 project).

Comment: when working with coding UI tooling definitely the simplest solution

Answer (score 8):

The solution for me was to convert my code from using CommonJS (`require`, `module.exports`, etc) to ES Modules (`import`, `export`, etc.)

The TypeScript documentation also appears to recommend ES Module syntax: [TypeScript Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

Of course there's a lot more to it than this, but as a start:

1. Replace instances of `require` with `import`, e.g.

   Replace:

   ```js
   const https = require('https');
   ```

   With:

   ```js
   import https from 'https';
   ```
2. Replace the default `module.exports` with `export default`, e.g.

   Replace:

   ```js
   module.exports = myVar ...
   ```

   With:

   ```js
   export default myVar ...
   ```
3. Replace other `module.exports` with `export`, e.g.

   Replace:

   ```js
   module.exports.myVar =
   ```

   or:

   ```js
   module.export = { myVar ... }
   ```

   With:

   ```js
   export myVar ...
   ```

More here: [From CommonJS to ES Modules: How to modernize your Node.js app](https://electerious.medium.com/from-commonjs-to-es-modules-how-to-modernize-your-node-js-app-ad8cdd4fb662)

Answer (score 8):

That´s the editor warning, becaouse, when you have open index.js which is compiled and also index.ts. you will see this.. but when you close index.js it will be ok.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my fix for my situation. Simple and Fast!!!

[image]

This happening when the block-scoped variable have declared somewhere in the source code.

To fix this, remove `module.exports =` and replace by `export default`.

Comment: Even though you made the no-no of posting code in images, replacing my `module.exports` with `export ...` removed the error for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the following `tsconfig.json` solved problem:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

There should be no `type`: `module` in `package.json`.

Answer (score 2):

I got the similar error when I was importing `express` incorrectly.
All I had to do was replace

```
const router = require('express').Router();
```

with

```
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();
```

Comment: I had to upgrade express to the latest version to get this to work, a small patch-update fixed a couple errors I had. Including, default not a function, and express not a function

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, and my solution looks like this:

```
// *./module1/module1.ts*
export module Module1 {
    export class Module1{
        greating(){ return 'hey from Module1'}
    }
}


// *./module2/module2.ts*
import {Module1} from './../module1/module1';

export module Module2{
    export class Module2{
        greating(){
            let m1 = new Module1.Module1()
            return 'hey from Module2 + and from loaded Model1: '+ m1.greating();
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can use it on the server side:

```
// *./server.ts*
/// <reference path="./typings/node/node.d.ts"/>
import {Module2} from './module2/module2';

export module Server {
    export class Server{
        greating(){
            let m2 = new Module2.Module2();
            return "hello from server & loaded modules: " + m2.greating();
        }
    }
}

exports.Server = Server;

// ./app.js
var Server = require('./server').Server.Server;
var server = new Server();
console.log(server.greating());
```

And on the client side too:

```
// *./public/javscripts/index/index.ts*

import {Module2} from './../../../module2/module2';

document.body.onload = function(){
    let m2 = new Module2.Module2();
    alert(m2.greating());
}

// ./views/index.jade
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  script(src='main.js')
  //
    the main.js-file created by gulp-task 'browserify' below in the gulpfile.js
```

And, of course, a gulp-file for all of this:

```
// *./gulpfile.js*
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    ts = require('gulp-typescript'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    browserify = require('gulp-browserify'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('default', function(callback) {

    gulp.task('ts1', function() {
        return gulp.src(['./module1/module1.ts'])
            .pipe(ts())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./module1'))
    });

    gulp.task('ts2', function() {
        return gulp.src(['./module2/module2.ts'])
            .pipe(ts())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./module2'))
    });

    gulp.task('ts3', function() {
        return gulp.src(['./public/javascripts/index/index.ts'])
            .pipe(ts())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/javascripts/index'))
    });

    gulp.task('browserify', function() {
        return gulp.src('./public/javascripts/index/index.js', { read: false })
            .pipe(browserify({
                insertGlobals: true
            }))
            .pipe(rename('main.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/javascripts/'))
    });

    runSequence('ts1', 'ts2', 'ts3', 'browserify', callback);
})
```

**Updated.**
Of course, it's not neccessary to compile typescript files separatly.
`runSequence(['ts1', 'ts2', 'ts3'], 'browserify', callback)` works perfect.

Comment: Just in case anyone is put off TypeScript by the verbosity and repetitiveness of that gulp file, no one does this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (using IntelliJ) `File` - `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` did the trick.

Comment: Same thing for WebStorm 2020.3. The hint that this was the right solution is that it was working before and the error started to appear after some apparently unrelated actions (e.g. unrelated changes commit, push, etc)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to change the:

`"target": "es5"` to `"target": "es6"` at `tsconfig.json` file.

If you cannot access this file just run:

`tsc --init` in the main directory.

Because initially the typescript will be sat to JavaScript es5 and that cannot understand the latest JavaScript syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using angular and I was trying to assign a variable in a method with colon instead of equal, like this:

`const user$ : this.service.getUser();`

It should've been:

`const user$ = this.service.getUser();`

Answer (score 0):

In my case refactor to use namespace solved most issues

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So... I did something, and it seemed to solve the problem, but I'm not really sure of unseen consequences, but it seems really simple.

I just put { at the start of the file and } at the end, therefore making a new block in the file...

file1.ts

```
{
  let co=require('co');
  //...
  module.exports=...
}
```

file2.ts

```
let co=require('co');
let f1=require('./file1');
//...
module.exports=...
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the ES6 import and that should fix the issue.
Make sure your tsconfig file is like the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

you can change the "outDir" and the "include" based on your own folder structure.

Answer (score -1):

It happens when variable co is already defined in the scope (maybe window/global object has it) and you are again declaring the variable with the same name.

if you replace let with var then it will not give an error but since you are using let then it is not allowed to re-declare the same variable using let

rename the variable to something else and the error will be gone.

Answer (score -2):

working on today's date: 12/22

example:

```
 button const =() {}
 export default button;

 export const button2(){}
```

--------------Import------------

```
import button, {ButtonIcon} from '../Button';
```

Comment: Please write your answers in English and according to [answer]. What do you mean by "12/22"? Please take the the [tour].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).