# 'Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable' in unrelated files

Tags: typescript, tsc

There is a simple TS package that is used as CommonJS modules and has no exports. TS files are compiled to JS files with the same name and used as `require('package/option-foo')`.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

option-foo.ts:

```
declare const GlobalVar: any;

function baz() {}

if (GlobalVar.foo) GlobalVar.baz = baz;
```

option-bar.ts:

```
declare const GlobalVar: any;

function baz() {}

if (GlobalVar.bar) GlobalVar.baz = baz;
```

The important part here is that `option-foo` and `option-bar` are *never used together*. There are other complimentary TS files in the project, but they don't affect anything, just needed to be transpiled to JS in one `tsc` run.

When `tsc` runs, it throws

> Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'GlobalVar'.
>
> Duplicate function implementation.
>
> Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'GlobalVar'.
>
> Duplicate function implementation.

for `GlobalVar` and `baz` in both files.

How can this be treated without complicating build process or the output from these two TS files?

Comment: In this specific case, you can have something like a `custom-typings.d.ts` file and just declare it there, if they're both `any`. You could also try changing the desired `--module` compilation (try AMD/System, as I believe they scope files individually).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As of TypeScript 4.7, this is solved via `"moduleDetection": "force"` in your tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ... Various options here, such as module ...
    "moduleDetection": "force"
  }
}
```

Reference:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleDetection

Original Github issue which drove this config: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14279

Comment: Thanks. I suppose this is the preferable solution now.

Answer (score 188):

**TL;DR** Just write `export {}` in the outermost scope of your files.

---

At some point there needs to be a semantic disambiguation for whether a file should be treated as a *module* (and have its own scope) or a *script* (and share the global scope with other scripts).

In the browser, this is easy - you should be able to use a `<script type="module">` tag and you'll be able to use modules.

But what about any other place that utilizes JavaScript? Unfortunately there isn't a standard way at this point to make that distinction.

The way that TypeScript decided to tackle the problem was to simply state that a module is *any file which contains an import or export*.

So if your file doesn't have any sort of top-level `import` or `export` statements, then you'll occasionally see issues with global declarations interfering with each other.

To get around this, you can simple have an `export` statement that exports nothing. In other words, just write

```
export {};
```

somewhere at the top-level of your file.

Comment: On second thought, I ended with this solution, it just works. Thanks.

Comment: This is the best explain about this problem. This problem confuse me a long while. Today, I finally find the reason.

Comment: so it's the TS compiler that is complaining, not a runtime issue, annoying. Is there a way to ignore TS errors like this?

Comment: You shouldn't try to ignore the errors in this case, especially if the errors come from `.ts` files, because those *will* actually experience a conflict.

Comment: Saved my time, this is the exact solution I was looking for. It's was annoying to see lots of warnings just because of this.

Comment: @DanielRosenwasser Couldn't it be a compiler setting? I thought that maybe moduleResolution or isolatedModules but no luck. I am working on forcing `truffle suite` to work with TS and it's kinda of a pain.

Comment: It works until you end up with SyntaxError: Unexpected token export.
I wish they'd just accept that this is a bug in typescript for NodeJS and develop a fix for it.

Comment: While I appreciate this hack, adding this is a smell. Why does TS consider an import a re-declaration? Modules are scoped. TS should really fix this bug..

Comment: I have a legacy code, which has this problem. Adding export {} is not an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 20):

`GlobalVar` and the functions are exposed to the global namespace, and TypeScript is warning you that the variable and the method name are re-declared. Because the two function are declared in the global namespace, you only need to declare them one time.

If you want to do this, use namespaces.

```
namespace foo {    
    declare const GlobalVar: any;
    function baz() {}
}

namespace bar {
    declare const GlobalVar: any;
    function baz() {}
}
```

You can call the functions in the same way as you call them in C#, by using the namespace name: `bar.baz` or `foo.baz`.