# React Native with Typescript 2.8 - Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'console'

Tags: typescript, react-native

Created a react-native starter project with Typescript which could run 2 weeks ago. Now when I try to run the project it gives error during the typescript compilation.

Using `skipLibraryCheck: true` in tsconfig.json fixes the error. 
But why is it throwing errors from ~/.nvm and ./node_modules directories?

Error (Updated for node_modules/.bin/tsc):

```
>  node_modules/.bin/tsc
node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts(8742,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'console'.
node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts(8750,18): error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'geolocation' must be of type 'Geolocation', but here has type 'GeolocationStatic'.
node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts(8753,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'navigator'.
node_modules/redux-thunk/index.d.ts(4,47): error TS2314: Generic type 'Dispatch<A, S>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/redux-thunk/index.d.ts(8,20): error TS2428: All declarations of 'Dispatch' must have identical type parameters.
node_modules/redux/index.d.ts(115,18): error TS2428: All declarations of 'Dispatch' must have identical type parameters.
node_modules/redux/index.d.ts(161,13): error TS2314: Generic type 'Dispatch<A, S>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/redux/index.d.ts(283,42): error TS2314: Generic type 'Dispatch<A, S>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/redux/index.d.ts(283,53): error TS2314: Generic type 'Dispatch<A, S>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/redux/index.d.ts(302,66): error TS2314: Generic type 'Dispatch<A, S>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/redux/index.d.ts(302,77): error TS2314: Generic type 'Dispatch<A, S>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/redux/index.d.ts(303,38): error TS2314: Generic type 'Dispatch<A, S>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/redux/index.d.ts(384,95): error TS2314: Generic type 'Dispatch<A, S>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/redux/index.d.ts(389,33): error TS2314: Generic type 'Dispatch<A, S>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/redux/index.d.ts(391,106): error TS2314: Generic type 'Dispatch<A, S>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/redux/index.d.ts(396,34): error TS2314: Generic type 'Dispatch<A, S>' requires 2 type argument(s).
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(21612,13): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'navigator'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(21788,13): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'console'.
```

Project details:

```
❯ react-native info
  Environment:
  OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
  Node: 9.11.1
  Yarn: 1.6.0
  npm: 6.0.0
  Watchman: 4.9.0
  Xcode: Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
  Android Studio: 2.3 AI-162.3934792

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1
  react-native: 0.55.3 => 0.55.3
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello-world-rn",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run tsc --",
    "clean": "rimraf lib",
    "lint": "tslint src/**/*.ts",
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "native-base": "2.4.3",
    "react-native": "0.55.3",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "redux": "4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "22.2.3",
    "@types/react": "16.3.13",
    "@types/react-native": "0.55.8",
    "@types/react-redux": "5.0.19",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "16.0.1",
    "babel-core": "6.26.3",
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "concurrently": "3.5.1",
    "eslint": "4.19.1",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "rimraf": "2.6.2",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "1.12.0",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "5.1.0",
    "tslint-react": "3.5.1",
    "typescript": "2.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "testRegex": "lib/.+\\.(test|spec).js$",
    "coverageDirectory": "coverage",
    "coverageReporters": [
      "text-summary",
      "html"
    ]
  },
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "lib/**/*.js",
    "!lib/**/*.spec.js",
    "!lib/**/*.index.js"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "strict": true,
    "types": ["react", "react-native", "jest"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": false
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "exclude": ["./android/*", "./ios/*", "./lib/*", "./node_modules/*"],
  "filesGlob": ["typings/index.d.ts", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
  "types": ["react", "react-native", "jest"]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900791/cannot-redeclare-block-scoped-variable-in-unrelated-files

Comment: @Sajeetharan: Here the errors are not in my code. It lies within node_modules/typescript itself.

Answer (score 5):

I can't really tell you what went through now and then which broke the typings, I can mostly give hints...

- When you call `tsc` from the terminal, it will use the global version of typescript, including its core typings, this is from where you are getting the ".nvm" errors. It is recommended that you use a local version (`node_modules/.bin/tsc`).
- I suggest you try adding "moduleResolution: node". I don't know why, just try it, maybe it fixes something.
- I'm not sure `redux-thunk` typings properly work with the new `redux@4.x`. Might be the source of your errors.

I usually just leave "skibLibCheck" on, we never know when libs were written with older versions of TS in mind, or even without the "strict" flag in mind.

EDIT FROM COMMENTS

- Seems react-native adds his own version of the base javascript typings, so you can disable the ones probided by TS through the `lib` flag, so they don't conflict.

Comment: [yep, typing in `redux-thunk` is broken with `redux@4.x` :/](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/issues/169)

Comment: Thank you. I've had moduleResolution set to node as well. Still doesn't work without the skipLibCheck. Getting errors in typescript even when I run node_modules/.bin/tsc. Updated the output accordingly.

Comment: I've noticed the "react-native" seems to be redeclaring the base es6 types (I've never used react-native). If react-native is supposed to declare the es6 typings instead of the TS default ones, then you can declare "lib:[]" or "noLib" on tsconfig so the default typings are not loaded.

Comment: The `@types/redux-thunk` may be breaking thinks and you might try remove it. It was never much useful anyway, it just declares a `Dispatch<any>` erasing all your reducer info (state and action type)...
I've been manually patching the dispatchers lately (thats a hack) https://github.com/wkrueger/redutser/blob/master/type-helpers.d.ts

Comment: I understand the redux thunk part. But what's with the typescript errors?

Comment: @wkrueger Can you update your answer with the option you mention in your comment?  For me, specifying `"lib": ["ES6"]` fixed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the "must be of type 'Geolocation'" one. Still trying to figure out how exactly to fix it, but in @types/react-native, Geolocation is defined as an alias of GeolocationStatic, but Geolocation is also a typescript type, and it needs to be the typescript type, not the @types/react-native type. It looks like the only place within @types/react-native/index.d.ts the Geolocation alias is used is

```
interface Navigator {
    readonly product: string;
    readonly geolocation: Geolocation;
}
```

Geolocation is assigned

```
export var Geolocation: GeolocationStatic;
export type Geolocation = GeolocationStatic;
```

Commenting these guys out after running `npm install` makes it work. I put it in an npm postinstall powershell script.

Yes, yes, it's hacky, and I'm positive there's a smooth, good solution to this. But if you just want it working and don't depend on these elsewhere, it could work. Another potential solution would be just to rename them.

Did some more snooping, looks like this is the official recommendation for the moment. Gotta love hacky fixes!
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/24573

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else stumbles upon this question when using `react-native` and `react-native-typescript-transformer`:

You can get this same issue when using `react-native-typescript-transformer` and `noEmit`, since global type declaration of `react-native/index.d.ts` are in conflict with `typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts`

From the [issue on github](https://github.com/emin93/react-native-template-typescript/issues/17):

> ... defining the ES6 base typings with the lib option seems to be enough to fix this issue...
>
> ...the noEmit option which is required by the react-native-typescript-transformer that causes this behaviour.

#### Solution

Specify in tsconfig.json valid library files to be included in the compilation. React Native is built on top of ES6 so that would be enough: `"lib": [ "es6" ]` in your `package.json`.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into same issue when using react-native along with typescript with nvm.

But finally resolved this by adding the "lib": ["ES6"] to my tsconfig.json file.

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow. Please explain in detail why adding that line is helping to solve the problem, or adding the current one as a comment(which you cannot right now, cause of your score). So, please follow my first suggestion.