# Errors when configuring react native with typescript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native, npm

To configure my react native project I followed this procedure minutely: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/05/07/using-typescript-with-react-native.
But this I'm going to compile I get fifteen errors from typescript compiler.

These are some of the errors:

- Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'navigator'.
- Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'geolocation' must be of type 'Geolocation', but here has type 'GeolocationStatic'
- Cannot find name 'Map'.
- Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type
- Duplicate identifier 'RequestInfo'.
- 'FormData' was also declared here.
- Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'console'.
- annot redeclare block-scoped variable 'navigator'.

Information:

```
"@types/react": "^16.7.3",
"@types/react-native": "^0.57.8",
"babel-jest": "23.6.0",
"jest": "23.6.0",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.49.1",
"react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.10",
"react-test-renderer": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
"typescript": "^3.1.6"
```

***UPDATE***

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": ["build", "index.js", "node_modules"]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "tsc": "tsc --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
    "react-native": "^0.57.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.7.3",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.8",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.49.1",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.10",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**App.tsx**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

**rn-cli.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    getTransformModulePath() {
      return require.resolve('react-native-typescript-transformer');
    },
    getSourceExts() {
      return ['ts', 'tsx'];
    },
  };
```

The other files are the files autogenerated by react-native.

Comment: Please provide code sufficient to reproduce the problem so we can find the cause.

Comment: You're absolutely right @Matt McCutchen, I just added details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the React Native type declarations conflict with the browser DOM declarations that TypeScript loads by default.  To stop loading the DOM declarations, set the `lib` option to `["es2017"]` (matching your `target`) in `tsconfig.json`.  (The default value of `lib` would include `es2017` as well as `dom`.)  There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50126200) (although the correct answer to set the `lib` option is buried in there) and additional discussion in [this issue report](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26218).

Comment: Thank you so much you've solved the problem. Do you believe that in the future I will have other conflicts caused by typescript, or can I go quietly? I've never used typescript for the front end and I'd rather not have other problems.

Comment: I'd say that realistically, you are likely to have further TypeScript-related problems at some point but they are likely to be solvable with a modest amount of work.  It's your decision whether you value the type checking and editor services enough to use TypeScript.  (I certainly do, or I suppose I wouldn't be here.)

Answer (score 1):

For those who are trying to configure react-native with typescript:

Check our [boilerplate](https://github.com/akveo/akveo-react-native-boilerplate/tree/typescript). This repo contains all initial configurations to make things working with new expo-31, babel 7, typescript and jest.