# Migrate Node.js project to TypeScript from plain ES6

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript3.0

Is started migrating a Node.js project from plain ES6 to TypeScript.

What I did:

```
npm install -g typescript
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

Setup `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
     "compilerOptions": {
         "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
         "experimentalDecorators": true,
         "moduleResolution": "node",
         "module": "commonjs",
         "target": "es6",
         "sourceMap": true,
         "outDir": "dist",
         "allowJs": true,
         "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
     },
     "exclude": [
         "node_modules",
         "dist",
         "docs"
     ]
}
```

Change all file extensions from `.js` to `.ts` (except in `node_modules`):

```
find . -not \( -path node_modules -prune \) -iname "*.js" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.js}".ts' - '{}' \;
```

Running `tsc` now leads to a ton of errors like these:

```
server.ts:13:7 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'async'.

13 const async = require('async');
     ~~~~~
```

Or these:

```
bootstrap/index.ts:8:7
8 const async = require('async');
        ~~~~~
'async' was also declared here.
```

Update:

The same happens for `retry` and other `npm` packages:

```
const retry = require('retry');
```

Changing `require` statements to ES6 `import` statements mostly fixed these but having to migrate a few thousands files at once is not feasable so I need a way to stick with `require` for a while. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm guessing that because async/await are both keywords in typescript that you cannot name your variable `async`. Incidentally, on a related note you'll probably want to retire the async library completely and use async/await with Promise-based constructs as well.

Comment: Yes, `async/await` definitely is a goal but first I need to get to transpile everything without errors and having to change as little as possible.

Comment: I updated the OP: the name `async` itself is not the cause of the issue, same happens with `retry` package and all others, even with local modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same problem as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900791/cannot-redeclare-block-scoped-variable-in-unrelated-files).

In order to be treated as ES module, a file should contain either `import` or `export` statement, otherwise a variable is considered to be declared in global scope by TypeScript compiler (even if this is not so at runtime).

The solution is same as in linked question, to add dummy `export {}`. This could be done in batch with regex replacement but in case CommonJS , `module.exports = ...` exports are already in use, there may be a conflict between them.

The use of CommonJS `require()` imports results in untyped code. All major libraries already have according `@types/...` or built-in typings. Existing NPM packages can be matched with a regex from code base in order to install relevant `@types/...` packages in batch, imports like `const async = require('async')` can be replaced in batch with `import async from 'async'`. This requires `esModuleInterop` and `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` options to be set.

Answer (score 7):

It's possible, but you'll still have to edit those files.

Either of those methods will be enough.

1. Replace `const ... = require()` with `import ... = require()`:

   ```
   import async = require('async');
   ...
   ```
2. Add `export {}` to the top of the file:

   ```
   export {};
   const async = require('async');
   ...
   ```

---

The reason of initial issue is that in TS different files are *not* modules unless they explicitly declared as modules, thus they are compiled/executed in the same global scope, and that's why `tsc` is reporting you that `async` variable can't be *redeclared*.

From [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html):

> In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level `import` or `export` is considered a module. Conversely, **a file without any top-level `import` or `export` declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well).**

Comment: When a file has an `import`/`export` statement, it's considered a module (as opposed to a script). Scripts are treated differently than modules. In your case you want modules. `const async = require('async');` is not considered an import statement, so a real import statement must be added.

Comment: Why does the existing `module.exports` not help here?

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler Why `module.exports` should work _in TypeScript_?

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler I'm sorry, I assumed you knew. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**async** is a protected keyword. When you use async/await you might skip the 'async' package. If you made ES6+ properly with **ECMAScript modules (ESM)** you also renamed all your files *.mjs, for example index.mjs. If you have the filename index.js it is most often assumed NOT to be ESM. You have to add types / interfaces to all your ES6 code, so depending on your case it might not be feasible to make all at once, that's why I give the example in ES2015+ ESM notation.

For TypeScript you should be able to use ESM because I guess you want more up to date notation. In order to use async at top level, the **async function** exist for doing that. **Example code for index.mjs that include ES2015+ import from ES5/CommonJS *.js with module.exports and ESM import/export and finally dynamic import:**

```
import { createRequireFromPath } from 'module'; // ESM import
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
const require = createRequireFromPath(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
// const untypedAsync = require('async');

class Index {

  constructor() {
    this._server = null;
    this.host = `localhost`;
    this.port = 8080;
  }

  set server(value) { this._server = value; }
  get server() { return this._server; }

  async start() {
    const http = await import(`http`); // dynamic import
    this.server = http.createServer(this.handleRequest);
    this.server.on(`error`, (err) => {
        console.error(`start error:`, err);
    });
    this.server.on(`clientError`, (err, socket) => {
        console.error(`start clientError:`, err);
        if (socket.writable) {
            return socket.end(`HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n\r\n`);
        }
        socket.destroy();
    });
    this.server.on(`connection`, (socket) => {
      const arrival = new Date().toJSON();
      const ip = socket.remoteAddress;
      const port = socket.localPort;
      console.log(`Request from IP-Address ${ip} and source port ${port} at ${arrival}`);
    });
    this.server.listen(this.port, this.host, () => {
      console.log(`http server listening at ${this.host}:${this.port}`);
    });
  }

  handleRequest(req, res) {
    console.log(`url:`, req.url);
    res.setHeader(`Content-Type`, `application/json`);
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(JSON.stringify({ url: req.url }));
  }
}

export default Index; // ESM export
export const randomName = new Index(); // Usage: import { randomName } from './index.mjs';

async function main() {
  const index = new Index();
  const cjs = require(`./otherfile.js`); // ES5/CommonJS import
  console.log(`otherfile:`, cjs);
  // 'async' can be used by using: cjs.untypedAsync
  await index.start();
}

main();

// in otherfile.js
const untypedAsync = require('async');
const test = {
  url: "url test",
  title: "title test",
};
module.exports = { test, untypedAsync }; // ES5/CommonJS export.
```

However, to use .mjs with typescript currently have some issues. Please look at the related typescript issues that are still open: [.mjs input files](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27957) and [.mjs output files](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18442). You should at least transpile your .ts to .mjs to solve your problems. The scripts might look like ([es6 to ts source](https://www.ceriously.com/blog/post.php?id=2017-10-16-es6-modules-today-with-typescript.md)):

```
// in package.json
"files": [ "dist" ],
"main": "dist/index",
"types": "dist/index.d.ts",
"scripts": {
    "mjs": "tsc -d && mv dist/index.js dist/index.mjs",
    "cjs": "tsc -m commonjs",
    "start": "node --no-warnings --experimental-modules ./dist/index.mjs"
    "build": "npm run mjs && npm run cjs"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
}

// in tsconfig.json
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "ES2017",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "strict": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are migrating a large project to TypeScript, I would suggest using some tool like this package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-to-typescript) which could automate some of the work.

You can write a script to open each file in the project and add `export {}` at the top as suggested by @Styx in his answer.