# Duplicate Function Implementation

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, gulp

I have one file, `app.ts` under my `scripts` folder, that gets copied to `wwwroot/scripts` by a `gulp` task. After the `gulp` task runs, I now also have a `wwwroot/scripts/app.ts` file, in which the sole function is red-underlined as duplicate. Is this normal, or is my `gulp` task, below, declared incorrectly?

```
var paths = {
    scripts: ["scripts/**/*.js", "scripts/**/*.ts", "scripts/**/*.map"]
};

gulp.task("default", function() {
    gulp.src(paths.scripts).pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/scripts"));
});
```

I see the raw `app.ts` file, from the root `scripts` folder also gets built into `*.js` and `*.js.map` files. Could this have something to do with the 'false positive' duplicate function?

Comment: In which folder is your tsconfig.json? Please post it as well here.

Comment: Does this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41975448/8786986 help you?

Comment: Why do you need to copy the `app.ts` into the `wwwroot/scripts`? What if you just set paths to `var paths = { scripts: ["scripts/**/*.js", "scripts/**/*.map"] };` ?

Comment: @ProfK why are you copying .ts files to your destination? how does your tsconfig look like?

Answer (score 3):

Don't copy the `.ts` files. You only need the compiled `.js` files in the `scripts` directory (unless you are doing something unusual with TypeScript source from there).

Then in your `tsconfig.json` file, add an [`exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) directive to exclude `wwwroot/scripts/**/*` in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

//VSCODE
This is an issue from VSCode. To fix it execute the following command

```
tsc --init
//to initialize the tsconfig.json in the folder.
```

//VISUAL STUDIO
In order to prevent functions to be in global scope, you can add export {}; on top (or just export this function):

```
// 1.ts
export {};

function test(){
    console log("File 1 Error");
}
// 2.ts
export {};

function test(){
    console.log("File 2 Error");
}
```

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio, not VSCode. I have added tags to show this.

Comment: I just updated the answer, try that out , if that works for you please upvote

Answer (score 0):

1- When you call glup with 2 references to the same code the .ts and .js he is going to transpila .. the .ts in to .js soo that's why you have 2 files.

You can try this:

```
var paths = {
    scripts: ["scripts/**/*.js", "scripts/**/*.map"]
};

gulp.task("default", function() {
    gulp.src(paths.scripts).pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/scripts"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a tsconfig.json file. You can generate the file using a simple command. Open terminal and type `"tsc -init".`