# error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'cucumber_1'

Tags: typescript, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I'm getting this error: `error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'cucumber_1'.`

I use webdriverIO 5, cucumber and typescript. This didn't happen before.

This is my package.json

```
{
 "name": "webdriverio_v5_typescript",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "Boilerplate project using version 5 WebdriverIO & TypeScript.",
 "repository": "https://github.com/jpolley/WebdriverIO_v5_TypeScript",
 "scripts": {
 "test:acc": "cross-env TEST_ENV='acc' wdio src/config/env/acc/acc.conf.js",
 "test:dev": "cross-env TEST_ENV='dev' wdio src/config/env/dev/dev.conf.js",
 "lint": "tslint --fix 'test/**/*.ts' && tslint --fix 'src/**/*.ts'",
 "report": "allure generate ./allure-results --clean && allure open",
 "report-ci": "allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report"
},
"author": "Jeremy Polley",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
"@applitools/eyes-webdriverio": "^5.8.4",
"@types/chai": "^4.2.2",
"@types/cucumber": "^4.0.5",
"@types/node": "^10.14.18",
"@wdio/allure-reporter": "^5.12.1",
"@wdio/applitools-service": "^5.8.0",
"@wdio/cli": "^5.13.0",
"@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^5.16.12",
"@wdio/local-runner": "^5.16.11",
"@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^5.16.10",
"@wdio/spec-reporter": "^5.12.1",
"@wdio/sync": "^5.16.11",
"allure-commandline": "^2.13.0",
"chai": "^4.2.0",
"chromedriver": "^78.0.1",
"cross-env": "^7.0.2",
"ts-node": "^8.10.2",
"tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
"tslint": "^5.20.0",
"typescript": "^3.9.7",
"wdio-chromedriver-service": "^5.0.2",
"webdriverio": "^5.16.11"
  }
 }
```

This is tsconfig.json file:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"lib": ["es2016"],
"skipLibCheck": true,
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "*": [
    "./*"
  ],
  "src/*": [
    "./src/*"
  ],
  "test/*": [
    "src/step_definitions/*"
  ]
},
/* Basic Options */
"target": "es2016",                       /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
"module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
// "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
// "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
// "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
// "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
// "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
// "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
// "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
// "outDir": "./",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
// "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
// "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
// "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
// "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
// "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
// "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

/* Strict Type-Checking Options */
"strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
"noImplicitAny": false,                   /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
// "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
// "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
// "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
// "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
// "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

/* Additional Checks */
// "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
// "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
// "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
// "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

/* Module Resolution Options */
// "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
// "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
// "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
// "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
// "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
"types": ["@wdio/sync","cucumber", "node", "@wdio/applitools-service"], /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
"typeRoots": ["./types"],
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,     /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
"esModuleInterop": true                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
// "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */

/* Source Map Options */
// "sourceRoot": "./",                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
// "mapRoot": "./",                       /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
// "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
// "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

/* Experimental Options */
// "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
// "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
 }
}
```

I couldn't find anything that would help me solve the problem.
I think it could be related to typescript version or some kind of dependency issue.
Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `export {}` at the top/outermost scope. The error is likely due to conflicts in the global declaration.

You can also refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41975448/9851536)

Comment: I already tried that in the past and it didn't help. Mysteriously when I try to do run my tests again after few days, then the error was gone. No changes were done from my side. And it started working again. Weird ... But thanks for reaching out.