# How I could improve the typing of this generic Box function?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

```
function Box(x: any) {
  return {
    inspect: () => `Box(${x})`,
    map: (f: (arg0: any) => any) => Box(f(x)),
    fold: (f: (arg0: any) => any) => f(x)
  }
}

const expr = Box(8)
  .map((x: number) => x + 8)
  .map((x: any) => Number(x))
  .map((x) => Math.cos(x))

console.log(expr.fold((x: any) => x))
```

How to improve the typing of the Box expression?

Comment: Take a look at [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Comment: You've tagged this [typescript-generics], so it seems you already know what to do. Can you show us your attempt, please, or explain what you don't understand about using generics?

Comment: Note that [I cannot reproduce](https://tsplay.dev/DWKn8m) your ESLint warning; perhaps something about your IDE configuration is weird?  Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900791/cannot-redeclare-block-scoped-variable-in-unrelated-files) is your problem?

Comment: Please ask only a single question per post. I've removed the one about ESLint, you might want to [create a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for it (but please give more details about how and where the warning happens)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Improving" the typing of `Box` is a little vague, but assuming you'd like `Box` to keep track of the type of value it contains, then I'd introduce a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) interface to represent the intended behavior:

```
interface Box<T> {
  inspect(): string;
  map<U>(f: (arg0: T) => U): Box<U>;
  fold<U>(f: (arg0: T) => U): U;
}
```

A `Box<T>`'s `inspect` method always produces a `string`.  Its `map()` method takes a callback turning a `T` into some other type `U` and produces a `Box<U>`, and `fold` takes a callback turning a `T` into some other type `U` and produces just a `U`.

Then you can annotate the function named `Box` as a generic one which accepts a value of type `T` and returns a `Box<T>`:

```
function Box<T>(x: T): Box<T> {
  return {
    inspect: () => `Box(${x})`,
    map: f => Box(f(x)),
    fold: f => f(x)
  }
}
```

Note how you can remove the annotations inside the implementation of `Box` because they are [contextually typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) by the expected `Box<T>` method parameter types.

---

Then when you use `Box`, you will see how the compiler keeps track of whether it is holding a `number` or a `string` (or anything else), and again the callbacks can be contextually typed so you can leave off their annotations:

```
const expr = Box(Math.PI / 2) // Box(1.5707963267948966)
  .map(x => Math.cos(x)) // Box(6.123233995736766e-17)
  .map(x => x.toFixed(4)) // Box("0.0000")
  .map(x => Number(x)) // Box(0)

console.log(expr.fold(x => x).toFixed(2)) // "0.00"
```

And the compiler will complain if you do the wrong thing, like treat a `string` as a `number`:

```
const badExpr = Box("Hello")
  .map(x => x.toFixed(2)); // error!
  // -------> ~~~~~~~
  // Property 'toFixed' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHsAeAeAKgPmQG8AoZZUAZwAcIEwAKASgC5lKwpQBzAbjOQBbONWwBVfAxhsGcKNwAMbXE2QBeQmNZos4-P3Ix0AGwAmeqTLmLlqjci1sx-AL4kSMAK4h6wdCB0cAgZMWzYMIMJScigIME8oAOjyChAaOjAZO0IAAwiGABIiTBcmHIAaAXJhajYYdUJ8mBCmJkqU5CMzOobOloE3N2QSBH8OZAhMaih1QIYAWTgwAAsAOgAFAElkAHpkACZVHb38gEZVgFYAdgUrgE4ANgBmfYf7gBYADkeHpgFVmohXqLFarUaUFpHE5YBgPVanfYvJ5PO53a5PN4PB4QAC0pyuf3IAJEQPsmFWYHQADFgJgIKYGO9WrtoZgGAAiBSrBQ8hTswnIYnUUmEABynkEACNoJCWXMFH8RmMTBBVsZ0NwGJNpqsugzML1MEwKdTafSGIcochOdy+e5RmkwMhJXBTABRKYzNRzdkACQgxnV-P+gINZJNNLpDMtvDl0Cg6CgAEIBMdkDiM5mcYQAH55-M51N7dYJ2hQMAAT2QAHJKZH6dXkKZ0BBKMgQOgnZNgON-MhK7QaxwuCBuNXVkA)

Comment: In theory [one doesn't even need the interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAITgDwDwBUB8AKNALkSwEpEBvAKEUQCcBTKEOpa22mMAZwAcHoxPOQC8ORAANUaPABIKaAL6kJAGhocAtgENexDAFVV+YEKiEyYg6PHTDJgqVLqOiYHAA2AE31GThPHNLHGtEMTdHDUUqaMQqCARuKEQGNF46MJR0PABZbSgACwA6AAUASUQAekQAJlIinV5c-OKE7nrGgjDxNCKoOAAxGDQGLzwAFicG3TwAORBNACMGOlIAbip4xM8GIo84AHM8VPSi928u8LR6-qGRsbrSIA), but then the types that TS infers get unwieldy.

Comment: Yeah, recursive anonymous types are .