# Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable with node built-ins / TS

Tags: typescript, scoping

Working on an existing typescript project. VS Code.

Create a new file in the server directory and get unique errors **just on that file**

this:

```
let path = require('path')
```

gives me the ole:

```
Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'path'.
```

whereas this is OK:

```
import * as path from "path"
```

Funnily enough, this

```
let fs = require('fs')
```

on its own also gives the same error, 
but if I include the `import * as path from "path"` above then that error goes away without touching it! Internal node modules are treated differently!

In many other files in the same project the

```
let fs = require('fs')
```

Gives **no error at all**

What is going on typescript?

I had a similar problem 2.5 years ago, and seems TS is still the same mystery box of configuration BS, now made even more opaque by VSC.

[cannot redeclare block scoped variable (typescript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758584/cannot-redeclare-block-scoped-variable-typescript)

this file is OK!

[image]

but in another file exact same code has the little squigglies!

[image]

but this magical combination is OK:

[image]

Comment: I can't say it much better than this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41975448 .  (Not voting a duplicate because the question isn't exactly the same.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `require`, instead use `import`.

The reason is, `require` is specific to `node`, where else `import` statement is transformed into either `require` or `define` based on target.

So when importing a module through `import`, TS compiler knows what and how to import. When you are importing through `require` method, everything is globally included in typescript. And thus the error.