# "Can't invoke class without new" and "Can't redeclare blocked-scoped variable" happening at the same time

Tags: typescript, apollo-datasource-rest

I started having an error while trying to use RESTDataSource:

`"Class constructor RESTDataSource cannot be invoked without 'new'"`

So I tried [this](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1388) solution and added `"target": "es2016"`. I don't get the error anymore.

But now I'm getting typescript compilation error
`error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Query'.`

Apparently this is happening because typescript doesn't recognize my files as modules.

So I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758584/cannot-redeclare-block-scoped-variable-typescript) solution and added `export {}` to my files so they get recognized as modules. But because my target is `es2016` I get `Unexpected token 'export'`

Is there any way I can solve both problems at the same time?

The errors are happening all over my code so I will include the whole repo: https://github.com/grochadc/filex-graphql-server

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["src/"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Comment: could you include some actual code? I can't really tell what the issue is because you haven't shown us what the code that is failing to compile looks like.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Sorry about that. The errors are happening all over my code so I included the whole repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pull out the relevant sections of the [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html#importing-from-modules)

> If you had the following Node/CommonJS code:
>
> ```
> var foo = require("foo");
>
> foo.doStuff();
> ```
>
> then you would write the following TypeScript code:
>
> ```
> import foo = require("foo");
>
> foo.doStuff();
> ```

and for [exporting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html#exporting-from-modules)

> You might have previously written that like so:
>
> ```
> function foo() {
>    // ... 
> } 
> module.exports = foo;
> ```
>
> In TypeScript, you can model this with the export = construct.
>
> ```
> function foo() {
>   // ...
> }
> export = foo;
> ```

then if you set `"module": "CommonJS"` in your tsconfig it will translate these back to what you have now, this is a legacy limitation that if you don't have import or export constructs it assumes it is not a module, so you just need to label your files as modules by using `import` and `export`