# NodeJS require error "Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'XXX'"

Tags: node.js, compiler-errors, syntax-error, require

I have my index.js file, where I have required my config.json file like this:

```
const config = require("../config.json");
```

config.json is just json file. Then I have imported my custom class like this:

```
let myClass = require('./myClass.js');
```

If I then need access to my config in myClass.js and put there same require like in my index.js, it gives me error:

```
Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'config'.
```

But if I don't place there that require, then on NodeJS running, it gives me error:

```
config is not defined
```

So, how can I use my config.json (or any package) with require, without renaming it in every file?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758584/cannot-redeclare-block-scoped-variable-typescript

Comment: Please show a larger context to this code.  It appears that there's another definition of the `config` variable somewhere in this same block that is conflicting and you are not allowed to redefine it in the same scope.