# TypeScript VS Code error 'Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable'

Tags: typescript

I'm going through the TypeScript tutorial here: https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-hello-world/

And I've got this in my app.ts file:

```
let message: string = 'Hello, TypeScript!';

let heading = document.createElement('h1');
heading.textContent = message;

document.body.appendChild(heading);
```

But on VS Code I'm getting a 'Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'message'.' error message after compiling. I've changed the variable name to something less generic, but I still get the same error.

Does anyone know why? Have I missed something obvious or is it an issue with my VS code set up? Pretty frustrating that I'm struggling on step 1 of the tutorial haha, any help is much appreciated!

*Edit: I even get it when I do a simple console.log: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWNuE.jpg

Comment: just add export {} at the end of file

Comment: Thanks, but if I do that I get this error in the browser [browser error](https://imgur.com/rpL5n0M) and the rest of the page won't render.

Comment: you need to compile it to js , browser doesnot support ts file

Comment: yeah sorry, I wasn't clear, that's after compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post helped solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68153061/9396175

Seems like it's an issue with VS Code and having the ts and js files open at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This error is likely occurring because you have two variables with the same name,delete the jascript file that was compiled from your typescript if its within your working folder in the vs code.or if you wanna keep it pass this above or bellow your typescript code.`export{}`